# Web Part Page layout

Tags: 2010, css, web-part-page, web-part-pages

I am not able figure out how to limit the width of the left column of one of the standard Web Part Page templates.

The one labeled 'Header, Left Column, Body' works as I would expect it to. The one labeled 'Header, Footer, 4 Columns,Top Row' does not. The left column expands out to 25% of the page or so. I want to constrain it to about 150px on the left side. I can not find a property in Designer that seems to work, not can I figure out what the difference in the templates is. If it's not in the template and is being set in CSS somewhere, I can't find that either.

The zones do not appear to have sizing properties at all, so I'm guessing that it needs to be set at the table column() tag above that. Surely I don't have to drop down to designing a whole new template just to get sizing. Someone please tell me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit width of a section irrespective of its inner content, Try using `<div>`
See this as example : http://www.techrepublic.com/article/creating-a-fixed-width-layout-with-css/5314471

Answer (score 0):

Surround your WebPartZone with DIV elements:

```
<div id="mynarrowdiv"><!-- WEBPARTZONEHERE --></div>
```

Then add CSS style:

```
#mynarrowdiv
{
    width: 150px; 
}
```